# Understanding $$watchers in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

1. What is $$watchers?
2. Angular keep watch on data with directives(most) and {{}}.

   a. How does it behaves in case of expression/filter/regular_data?
   b. On what watch is kept on(in case of expression/filter)?
3. ngIf create child scope so it has watch on data passed to it
   and also parent keeps watch on it. This can affect performence.
   Does this has much impact on performance?